# printf doesn't print if I have msgrcv call later in program

Tags: c, posix

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
printf("Temp is");

msgrcv(externalQid, &incomingMsg, sizeof(incomingMsg)-sizeof(long), 0, 0);
}
```

printf never actually prints in this case...it does however get printed if I don't have the msgrv call.. It is making it very hard to debug my program.  Any ideas?

Comment: who is `temp`? where do you declare you variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting a newline character at the end of your printf. I'm not intimately familiar with the 'why', but it solved a similar problem I had a while ago.

Comment: @James It's probably because your implementation of printf happens to flush on newlines

Comment: From what I understand(so don't take it as fact), there's a buffer that you write to when calling printf. This buffer gets printed to the screen when it is full, or certain characters are entered. This keeps the terminal flowing smoothly by printing only when it matters.

Comment: `stdout` is line-buffered by default when it's writing to an interactive device. You can also add a call `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf` to force the output to be flushed, if you don't want to add a newline.